# The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Guid', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.String'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I've looked through so many similar questions here, but none were able to solve our problem or explain why this might be happening.

We created an EDMX from an existing database, and used MVC 4 scaffolding to automatically generate the controller and views for us.  The Index page is fine, but when we choose an entity to Edit, this error is thrown. There are no custom editors in our solution, nor is this a partial page update.

The controller code for the edit page is this:

```cs
public ActionResult Edit(int id = 0)
{
   MessageProfile messageprofile = db.MessageProfiles.Find(id);
   if (messageprofile == null)
   {    
      return HttpNotFound();
   }
   return View(messageprofile);
}
```

The model declaration on Edit.cshtml is

```
@model Web.UI.Areas.Admin.Models.MessageProfile
```

and the error is thrown at

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.APIKey)
```

The EDMX has APIKey as a GUID, the generated model class has APIKey as a model, and the EditorFor indicates it's an editor for a GUID when we hover over it in the code.  We are completely stumped where a String is entering the process.  Appreciate any help.

Comment: try creating your own `GUIEditor.cshtml` and call it from `EditorFor(model,"GUIEditor")`

Comment: Can you show us how is defined `MessageProfile` ?

Answer (score 0):

Having workd with ASP.NET Dynamic Data quite often, my expectation was that there would be an editor already present for every primitive type in MVC scaffolding.  There is not, and attempts are made to do an implicit conversion.  When that fails, this error usually gets thrown.

In this case, the easy solution was to use Html.TextBoxFor instead of Html.EditorFor.  It's a weird case, but the value is being pasted in from an email.  In other cases, we made the form better with a lookup and dropdownlist.

Had we wanted to have a GUID-specific editor, we would have had to create our own.  All we would have ended up with was a textbox anyway, so that's why the first solution was the simplest.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me as well. The problem for me was that I created custom Editfor templates and I did not include one for System.Guid. Since it could find one to match system.Guid it would try to use System. String thus generating that error.

If this is the case in your EditorTemplates folder add a cshtml called Guid, then add the following:

```
@model System.Guid
@Html.TextBox("", ViewData.TemplateInfo.FormattedModelValue)
```